# CssRules that make 'box-sizing:border-box' not working in IE9-10

Tags: html, css

I have some css-rules that don't work correct in ie9-10.
There is parent div (which has box-sizing:border-box) and child element.
When hover on child element the parent div expands (like it doesn't have box-sizing property)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <button class="btn">Just hover me</button>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    width: 350px; 
    background-color: #dedede;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    min-height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    border: 10px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn:hover{
    border-color: #89bede;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #137ebe;
}
```

But interesting moment in this case that if i delete just ONE of the next properties, example works:

- min-height (of .wrap)
- overflow:hidden (of .wrap)
- box-sizing (of .wrap)
- border-color (of .btn:hover)  (really don't know why this property also affects)

As you may suggest i need all this properties and wouldn't like to delete any of them.
So, is there some solution, that can make it work in IE9-10 without deleting properties?

example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dpN3p/

Comment: and it does too even writing the full border rule like this : border: 10px solid #89bede; ?

Comment: I think @GCyrillus is right, try using the same rules on both `.btn` and `.btn:hover`

Comment: are you sure you have a proper `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: @GCyrillus , it doesn' help. Only if i keep the  same rules of border (border: 10px solid #cccccc;   or even border:#cccccc) it works, but i need the border-color to be changed on hover.

Comment: @JFK , DOCTYPE is html

Comment: @zhenetta : sure it is, but IE doesn't play well your css without a proper `DOCTYPE` (ever heard about quirks mode?)

Comment: @JFK but i set <!DOCTYPE html> isn't that the proper doctype for IE10??

P.S. i also tried 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">  
and  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">   
and it doesn't work too.

Comment: funny, you have many rules that an trigger layout , unable to test i would start by removing the inline-block property. button is already inline-block and see if position: relative/static avoids IE engine to get confused or make it even more confused ... IE5-7 use to be the kings of these incoherent behaviors :)

Comment: here the improbable test idea http://jsfiddle.net/dpN3p/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus your ideas also doesn't help.:(   I tried to remove inline-block or change the position property.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this problem in my work today. It has to do with `box-sizing` property on the parent div being ignored once the child is hovered over.

**The solution is to change the `box-sizing` to `content-box` (the default), and adjust the `min-height` and `width` accordingly.** Since `content-box` adds `padding` on top of the `height` and `width`, `padding` values must be manually subtracted from your size values.

```
.wrap {
    width: 330px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    min-height: 30px;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/dpN3p/2/.